# How to get gliderlabs/registrator running on on Bluemix

Tags: containers, ibm-cloud, service-discovery

I'm trying to get gliderlabs registrator running on Bluemix, but I'm having issues as the container won't start with 
O400 The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port

What I think is happening is that my docker host is running on tcp://containers-api.eu-gb.bluemix.net:8443 - so the docker rest api's are https.  However I suspect the gliderlabs/registrator is using http by default.

So anyone got any ideas how to get this to work ?

Steve

Answer (score 0):

Looking at that package, it uses the library github.com/fsouza/go-dockerclient to access the docker remote api, specifically the `NewClientFromEnv()` call.  Per the readme for go-dockerclient, it should pick up the env vars for https if they're there - i.e. make sure you're exporting all three env vars: `DOCKER_HOST`, `DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY`, `DOCKER_CERT_PATH`.

Another possibility - per reading the comments about registrator - you may wish to check that you're using `gliderlabs/registrator:master` instead of `gliderlabs/registrator:latest`.  Just pulled both to check, and  "latest" is 14 months old, vs 6 days for "master".